# How to remove Special character in <pre> in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need some advice/ help on how to remove special character in html

I need to remove the special character: **"kind": "pagespeedonline#result"**. I already try some code to move it but can't.

I wanted the result to be **kind:** **pagespeedonline#result**

I want those **quotation mark(")** to be remove and become just plain text

```html
"kind":"pagespeedonline#result",
 "id": "https://www.example.com/",
 "responseCode": 200,
 "title": "",
 "score": 55,
 "pageStats": {
  "numberResources": 93,
  "numberHosts": 22,
  "totalRequestBytes": "19710",
  "numberStaticResources": 62,
  "htmlResponseBytes": "289086",
  "cssResponseBytes": "503970",
  "imageResponseBytes": "467782",
  "javascriptResponseBytes": "1279195",
  "otherResponseBytes": "202171",
  "numberJsResources": 28,
  "numberCssResources": 11.
```

[Check the image Please!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ0S2.png)

Comment: Do you mean to remove the `kind`?

Comment: what are you passing to create the data in pre? You could unset it `unset($foo->kind);`

Comment: the character " "

Comment: Now you should post the code that you tried and explain specifically what didn't work about that code.

Comment: I only need a plane text like Hello World:Hi hello

Comment: Please read [ask] then write a more informative question that includes how the text is inserted and what expected results are. Also read [mcve]

Comment: Post your expected out put in question

Comment: @RavinderReddy: please check this - http://webbatlas.com/url-scan/google-url-scan.html "i wanted the special character to be remove" when you scan a site...

Comment: Do you want it to be removed from all the json or only from "kind"?

Comment: From all of them @pr1nc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a string with data in JSON format. 
To display one element with removed double quotation marks using PHP:

```
$data = ''; // your JSON data here
$json = json_decode($data, true);
echo 'kind: '.$json['kind'];
```

With JavaScript:

```js
var data = {
"kind":"pagespeedonline#result",
 "id": "https://www.example.com/",
 "responseCode": 200,
 "title": "",
 "score": 55,
 "pageStats": {
  "numberResources": 93,
  "numberHosts": 22,
  "totalRequestBytes": "19710",
  "numberStaticResources": 62,
  "htmlResponseBytes": "289086",
  "cssResponseBytes": "503970",
  "imageResponseBytes": "467782",
  "javascriptResponseBytes": "1279195",
  "otherResponseBytes": "202171",
  "numberJsResources": 28,
  "numberCssResources": 11
  }
  };
  alert('kind: ' + data.kind);
  // this will display JSON data converted to string with removed double quotation marks
  alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4).replace(/\"/g, ""));
```

Comment: Hi @camelsWriteInCamelCase if im going to use it in all them?

Comment: When using alert...its pops up... alert...mgs

Comment: The line of code with second alert shows how you can get the object data without double quotation marks. You can assign parameter `JSON.stringify(data, null, 4).replace(/\"/g, "")` to some variable and do what you need with this string.